# Calculating $x^{103} \equiv 2 \pmod{143}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to find x, given that:
$0\leq x \leq 143$ and $x^{103}\equiv 2 \pmod{143}$.
I tried to use Euler's theorem $p(143)=120$, but it didn't help.

Comment: With a program, I calculated that the answer is 128

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find a way without using computer.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve each of the following separately and find the common solutions:

$x^{103} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$

$x^{103} \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$

They simplify by Fermat's little theorem to:

$x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$

$x^7 \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$

It is now easy to check all small cases to get the solutions:

$x \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$

$x \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$

When solved these give:

$x \equiv 128 \pmod{143}$

Answer (score 3):

If you want to, you can use Euler to say (mod $143$) that $x^{120}\equiv 1$ so that $x^{-17} \equiv 2$

Now note that $103=6\times 17 +1$ so that $$2\equiv x^{103}\equiv (x^{17})^6x$$ whence , on dividing by $(x^{17})^6$, and using $x^{-17}\equiv 2$ $$x\equiv 2\times (x^{-17})^6\equiv 2^7\equiv 128$$

Comment: well done! Thanks

Comment: Good Observation

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$x^{103}\equiv2 \pmod {13}$$
$$x^{103}\equiv2 \pmod {11}$$

en

$$x^7\equiv2 \pmod {13}$$
$$x^3\equiv2 \pmod {11}$$

$7$ is the common  primitive root $\bmod {13}$ and $\bmod {11}$

$7^{11}\equiv2 \pmod {13}$, $7^3\equiv2 \pmod {11}$, and

if $(7^t)^7\equiv2 \pmod {13}$, $7t\equiv 11 \pmod {12}$, then $t=5\pmod {12}$

if $(7^s)^3\equiv2 \pmod {13}$, $3s\equiv 3 \pmod {10}$, then $s=1\pmod {10}$

so, the root $x$ is decided by

$$x\equiv 7^5\equiv 11 \pmod {13}$$
$$x\equiv7 \pmod {11}$$

then

$$x\equiv128 \pmod {143}$$

Comment: The last line's "the" must be "a".

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it should be noted that in general it may not be the case that two prime moduli have the same primitive root. It just happens to be so in this case.

Comment: @user21820 Your statement is More difficult than OP's problem! Can you construct a counterexample?

Comment: @Clin: The first one is $(7,11)$, which have primitive roots $\{3,5\},\{2,6,7,8\}$ respectively. I got them from http://dbfin.com/2012/04/primitive-roots-modulo-the-first-100-prime-numbers/ and verified them by hand.

Comment: @Clin: Sorry the first is $(3,7)$ because $2$ is the only primitive root mod $3$ but isn't a primitive root mod $7$. I missed it when I glanced at the table...

Comment: @Clin: Wait if you allow primitive roots bigger than the moduli then of course it's always possible, if you only allow primitive roots up to the largest moduli then $(7,11)$ is a counter-example.

Comment: NO! I think two prime moduli always have the same primitive root! Consider $3+7m$,$2+11n$ there are infinite prime cush that $p=3+7m=2+11n$

Comment: @Clin: See my comment just before yours..

Comment: @user21820 Thank you very much!